# Filewriter does not write all numbers into my file

Tags: java, file, filewriter

My code is supposed to do the following. It reads the last primenumber of a textfile and continue to write all following prime numbers down.

```
 public static void PrintPrimesIntoFile(){
            File primenumbers = new File("C:/Users/Leon/IdeaProjects/NumberTheory/primes.txt");
            String lastprim = "";
            int lp = 0;
            Writer wr = null;

            //create file or check existence
            if(!primenumbers.exists())
            {
                try{
                    primenumbers.createNewFile();
                }catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            //read last line
            try{
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(primenumbers);
                while(sc.hasNext()){
                    lastprim = sc.next();
                }
                lp = Integer.parseInt(lastprim);
                lp++;

            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(lastprim);


            //print next numbers
            try{
                wr = new FileWriter(primenumbers, true);
                while(true){
                    if(NumberTheoryFunctions.CheckPrime(lp)){
                        wr.write(new Integer(lp).toString());
                        System.out.println(lp);
                        wr.write("\r\n");
                    }
                    lp++;
                }
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

The problem is only about the loop inside the last try and catch block. I check if a number is prime, if it is, I write it into the file. If not, I head to the next number. The programm is supposed to do this until i close it.

My problem is, not every number that is checked either it is prime or not is written into the file. For example, my console shows the number 1022821 when i stop the programm, but in my file the last number is 1020893.

It even happens (and that is the real problem) that a single number does not get written down entirely. For example my programm was supposed to write 1022701, but it just wrote 102 and stopped.

Since the last loop goes for ever, I even do not have a possibility to write `wr.close()` anywhere in the code.

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: so if the file ends with a prime number u will print the same as result if not u will find the next closes prime number ?

Comment: Nono, I only write primes into the file. When I start the program new, it starts where it stopped before, so I dont have to check numbers that were already written into the file again.

Comment: so lets say ur last number in file was 7 then when u start the program it should print 7 and insert 11 ? also ur while loop will never ending i.e. while(true) why is that so ?

Comment: You could flush() the Writer occasionally. And it would be best to find some way to exit the loop eventually and do a proper close.

Comment: When it reads 7, it continues to write all primes greater than 7 into the file. But it doesn't replace it. When the file ends with 7, the programm adds 11,13,17,.. until I stop it. And at the end I got a complete list of all primes from 2 to (in this example 17).

Comment: by stop u mean user input or just close the program ? force stop ?

Comment: just close it. Thats is the problem, I have no option to use wr.close() before it stops.